# Is it possible to show all options from an HTML Select form field at once without clicking it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, selection

I am using the X-Editable jQuery edit in place library for a Task Status selection field.  All it;s stages are shown below from the process of:

1. Clicking the Status
2. It then hides the status SPAN and reveals the hidden Selection field.
3. You can click the selection field which makes it dropdown and show all available options.
4. Clicking a new Selection option value then shows a loading spinner image while it makes an AJAX request to save the value
5. It then Shows the new selected Status Value SPAN.
6. Clicking again restarts the cycle/process.

[image]

---

I am however trying to come up with a better way to select a new value.  There are only 3 selection options so I would like to possibly show all 3 items at once instead of requiring you to click the dropdown to see the other 2 options.

Is it possible to do that with a basic Selection or does it require a **Multi-select** field?

Comment: why not use a radio button set?

Comment: @DanielA.White I hadn't thought of it, that might be a better option! thanks.  With a Radio, I could then even show a real style preview of the end result next to each radio with background color and all

Comment: Interesting, just realized X-Editable does not have Radio button option!  However it looks like someone made an addition for it here https://gist.github.com/lisacatalano/7360603

Answer (score 38, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/n1k5cLx0/

Are you looking for a list or do you still want a dropdown with the options shown as default. For a list style you could use the size attribute with the select element.

**HTML**

```
<select size="3">
  <option>Not Started</option>
  <option selected>In Progess</option>
  <option>Completed</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: do be aware that `size` is not respected by mobile devices, but it works fine on desktops

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks.  I am also looking at this Radio list plugin that someone made for X-Editable which I have a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/gcL92o48/ it;s pretty cool for anyone looking for this custom plugin

Answer (score -4):

$("#Id_Selecteventtype")[0].selectedIndex = 1;

Comment: I'm not sure how this piece of code is related to the question