# Is it possible to style a `<select>` to behave like a vanilla `<div>`?

Tags: html, css, forms, print-style

Is there a way to style the following markup …

```html
<select>
  <option>Canteloupe</option>
  <option>Canteloupe</option>
  <option selected>Crabapple</option>
</select>
```

[image: basic select]

… so that all the options are visible at once?

I would like it to behave *as though* all the elements are `<div>`s, so I can lay out each option for a printed version of the form.

Like this:

```html
<div>
  <div>Canteloupe</div>
  <div>Canteloupe</div>
  <div>Crabapple</div>
</div>
```

[image: desired presentation of select]

I have tried `-webkit-appearance: none`, which removes the operating system appearance, but doesn't stop the select element from hiding its non-selected `<option>`s.

A lot of built-in html elements can have their built in styling overridden "back to nothing", but it seems as though `<select>` is magic, and has user agent behaviour that can't be undone.

I don't have to support old browsers (e.g. IE11)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to show all options from an HTML Select form field at once without clicking it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010787/is-it-possible-to-show-all-options-from-an-html-select-form-field-at-once-withou)

Answer (score 0):

For you case I think using [multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple) attribute would be a valid way to have all the options laid-out for printing:

```css
#cars {
  border: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<select id="cars" name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">



</body>
</html>
```